# How to filter custom directory roles from Powershell Or CLI

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, azure-rbac, role-based-access-control, azure-identity

I have few custom directory roles with specific permissions. I attempted to do it from graph but no use, throwing errors.

Is there any other possible way to get that list from Powershell Or CLI.

```
Get-AzRoleDefinition
```

Getting all roles, how to add custom role filter for this command?

Comment: You should be able to fetch only your custom roles with `Get-AzRoleDefinition -Custom`

Comment: Throwing `Get-AzRoleDefinition: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to get the custom roles using PowerShell**

Here is the script to get Azure **custom roles** with **Filter**.

```
#import and Install Az Module
Import-Module Az.Accounts
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
#connect-Azure Account
Connect-AzAccount
#Get All Azure AzRoleDefinition
Get-AzRoleDefinition
Get-AzRoleDefinition -Name Reader
#Get Custom Roles
Get-AzRoleDefinition -Custom |? {$_.IsCustom -eq $true}| FT Name,IsCustom,Id
```

Output with **Filter** command.

[image]

Reference : [Azure custom role using Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/tutorial-custom-role-powershell)